# Emulate multisignature wallet

Tags: public-key

I have a blockchain wallet with a single signature wallet, is there a way of making this wallet "multi-signature"? F.e can we use some secret sharing scheme to distribute the single private key among custodians? What I need in the end is to make several users control access to a single wallet.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific here in order to get a useful answer.  What kind of wallet are you talking about?  Are you talking about a _single specific wallet_ which you _already created_ and you _now_ need to share between multiple users without changing the public key, or are you talking about _designing a new kind of wallet_ which needs to interoperate with existing verifiers, or are you designing a _new system altogether_ for which interoperability with existing verifiers is not necessary?

Comment: When I answered, I assumed you meant that you already have a specific wallet whose public key is already fixed and which you _now_ want some subset of several users, say $k$ of $n$, to _have to agree_ on any transactions with the wallet before they are valid.  But it's possible I read too much into your phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Responding to Squeamish Ossifrage) Threshold signatures do not require any single member to reconstruct the whole secret. Ideally each party produces a partial signature and only when they are all combined is the signature valid.

#### [Douglas R. Stinson, Reto Strobl - Provably Secure Distributed Schnorr Signatures and a (t, n) Threshold Scheme for Implicit Certificates](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2001/corr2001-13.ps)

This enables a pre-determined group to share a single schnorr identity without changing the verification side of the protocol. Any subset of $k$ members may collaborate to sign a common message. The secret sharing is verified and the dealer cannot cheat. The co-signers cannot be tricked by their peers.

#### [MuSig: n-of-n threshold schnorr via aggregation](https://blockstream.com/2018/01/23/musig-key-aggregation-schnorr-signatures.html)

MuSig also doesn't change the verification side. A group is derived from the list of all public keys required to sign the common message. With only two-rounds of communication, the group produces the signature.

#### [Crypto conditions: off-chain contracts resolving to minimal proofs of execution](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomas-crypto-conditions-02)

Crypto-conditions are a form of multi-sig contract that doesn't attempt to aggregate any identities. Instead it uses hash commitments to commit to some boolean circuit. I.e. A contract may require "either Alice, or both Bob and Carol", or any arbitrary logic. The contract is a single hash. The proof of execution reveals only the relevant branches. The contract is valid if all leaves are valid and all intermediate steps have appropriate thresholds.

ANY-k is implemented as k-of-n. OR/ANY as 1-of-n. AND/ALL as n-of-n. A fullfillment may be either a hash-lock that is just a revealed symmetric secret key, or a signing public key whose corresponding secret signs the transaction that it approves.

Any irrelevant (or dead/unresolved) branches are truncated to a single hash commitment; enabling an arbitrarily large contract to resolve to a minimal proof.

### Conclusion

I believe it would be worth implementing all of these. Notably $(t,n)$ enables a group to divide their signing right such that no single, or fewer-than-t subset may impersonate the group. N-of-N MuSig enables opportunistic groups to compress the crypto-condition contracts, which can describe any boolean circuits - not just subsets or all.

**bonus**: BLS is signature scheme that supports aggregation of many distinct-signatures. But this is not schnorr-friendly and does not work with any curves not explicitly designed to be pairing-friendly.

Comment: Thank you, it the first protocol applicable to bitcoin? waves?

Comment: @Solon Yes, it could be used for cryptocurrencies. Is it? AFAIK not yet. But there have been efforts in switching to schnorr to enable MuSig; which would imply being able to use $(t,n)$.

Comment: the question is can I do it by myself? can I share bitcoin/waves private key, between n nodes to allow only a set of k to produce a signature? without changing chain verification method

Comment: Using ECDSA? No. If you switch to say Ed25519, an EdDSA that uses schnorr, then yes. There may be other ways for ECDSA, but I don't follow ECDSA because EdDSA is far more useful.

Comment: With BTC and other ECDSA, you must use the "script" to implement multisig. I'm not versed in the BTC script language, but I'm pretty sure they have a fat-$(t,n)$ variant.

Comment: as far as I know bitcoin multisig is constrained with the maximum of 3 custodians. Maybe I a fell for XY mistake here. I am going to explain my initial problem here: I need to transfer tokens between 2 chains - one is controlled with federation with a BFT consensus with n custodians. what I want is to produce atomic swap with a chain not having smart contracts or an honest multisig. My assumption was I need the same custodians somehow controlling some wallet with the same threshold (2f+1 of 3f) as in the side chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74962/discussion-between-cypherfox-and-solon).

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes, if you destroy the inputs to the secret-sharing scheme—but the moment any one party *assembles* all the shares to make a signature, that party has the unilateral power to make signatures until you destroy that party.  So the party who reassembles the secret is a single point of *eternal* failure every time you need to make a signature.

Comment: I understand the drawback of this approach, that is why I  only used it as examples, is there any schemes that don't have such problem?

Comment: Yes: real threshold/collective signatures, _a.k.a._ multisignatures.  See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50448/49826) for a quick sketch of a limited $n$-of-$n$ one (which requires no changes to verifiers) and some references to relevant literature.  But you will need to make a _new wallet_ even for the limited one sketched there with all the parties participating in the key generation—and change the software in the _verifiers_ if you use a $k$-of-$n$ threshold signature scheme for $k < n$ that they don't already support.

Comment: So, if I have simple asymmetric encryption wallet I can only implement n-of-n threshold, but not k-of-n?

Comment: @Solon Threshold signatures aren't about _encryption_ —  they're about _signature_. Imagine a document with two lines on which to sign, which is valid only if two different authorized parties sign it. Whether your particular kind of wallet can even be adapted to use an $n$-of-$n$ threshold signature like I sketched depends on what kind of signature scheme it uses. Need a lot more details to say what you can and can't do with your particular wallet. _E.g.,_ I suspect the $n$-of-$n$ scheme I sketched can't be made to work with ECDSA, so it's no good for Bitcoin (though BTC has multisig wallets).

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage You can use a verified signature sharing scheme with a threshold signature scheme without enabling any party (not even the dealer) to recover the secret key. Each party produces a partial signature. See my answer for a reference.