# Secure multi-party computation for digital signature

Tags: rsa, public-key, elliptic-curves, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

Is there any *practical* algorithm that will allow to use public key cryptography (RSA or ECC) in the following way

1. There are **N** parties. Up to **M** are malicious adversaries (were trusted, but got taken over silently). I will be happy with solution for any **N** and **M** = 1.
2. Parties can communicate securely. No eavesdropping.
3. Private key **K** is somehow split and shared between all **N** parties. Maybe something like Shamir's Secret Sharing. No party can recover **K** without other **N**-1 parties data.
4. All parties receive some data **S**.
5. Parties should be able to encrypt **S** (actually hash of **S**, I need digital signature) with **K**, but without revealing any useful information about **K** to malicious adversary; or should detect that there are too many malicious adversaries and abort.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a threshold signature scheme, or group signatures? It works approximately the same, at least M of N parties agree on a single message and communicate in order to sign it.

Comment: FYI: signature is _not_ ‘encryption with the private key’.  It's a separate concept, with different computations.

Comment: @Natanael No, because I have to integrate this solution with existing PKI, so completely different type of signature will not do.

Comment: Some references on Schnorr-type threshold signatures, particularly with EdDSA: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50450

Comment: @adontz there exists some transparent threshold schemes that can work with existing keys in existing ECC curves. Also, encryption can work too (technically key exchange, then encryption)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly straight-forward method, using RSA:

Set-up phase (assuming a trusted dealer that participates only with the setup phase; such a setup without a dealer can be done, but is considerably more complicated):

- The dealer selects a random RSA public/private keypair $(n,e)$ and $(d)$
- The dealer then selects $N$ values $d_1, d_2, …, d_N$ with the constraint that $d_1 + d_2 + … + d_N \equiv d \pmod{ \lambda(n) }$
- The dealer privately sends $d_i$ to party $i$, and publishes the public key $(n, e)$

Signature generation phase:

- Each party gets a copy of the value to be signed $S$
- Each party $i$ deterministically pads $S$ (perhaps using PKCS #1.5 signature padding, perhaps using PSS using randomness seeded by $S$), and then raises that to the power of $d_i$ modulo $n$; that is, it computes $sig_i = \text{Pad}(S)^{d_i} \bmod n$
- Each party sends $sig_i$ to a collector, which computes $sig = sig_1 \cdot sig_2 \cdot … \cdot s_n \bmod n$, and broadcasts it
- Everyone checks if $sig$ is a valid signature to the value $s$; if not, then a malicious party is detected

Lets go through the requirements:

- No party can recover secret key $d$ without other $N-1$ parties data

Met; without all the $d_i$ values, you cannot reconstruct the $d$ value.

- 5.Parties should be able to encrypt $S$ (actually hash of $S$, I need digital signature) with secret key $d$, but without revealing any useful information about $d$ to malicious adversary

Met; each party acts as an Oracle that'll compute $f(x) = x^{d_i} \pmod n$, however if the Discrete Log problem is hard, you can't recover $d_i$ from that.

Now, a malicious party could perform a Denial of Service attack (by not computing his $sig_i$ value properly.  On the other hand, I believe that this will always be true if you require that $N-1$ parties be unable to recover the key (or otherwise generate arbitrary signatures, which is effectively the same as recovering the key), and so I would claim that this meets your requirement.