# Secure multi-party random number generation

Tags: protocol-design, multiparty-computation

This question is actually continuation of my previous one.

[Secure multi-party computation for digital signature](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67548/secure-multi-party-computation-for-digital-signature)

to implement solution there, I have to generate random data for padding (I will use PSS).

1. There are **N** parties. Up to **M** are malicious adversaries (were trusted, but got taken over silently). I will be happy with solution for any **N** and **M** = 1.
2. Parties should send to each other some random data **d[i]** and each party based on all **d[1..N]** should generate some final random value **R**.

From one side, value should be one and the same for all parties, i.e. calculation should be a fixed predictable process and all parties should get one and the same value **R**. From another side, malicious adversary party should not be able to affect randomness of **R[i]**, i.e. even malicious adversary should not be able to generate **d[m]** to get specific **R**.

Looks like I can achieve this by simply hashing all **d[i]** values in predictable order. For instance sort **d[i]** and calculate hash of **"well-known-secure-prefix"** + **d[1..N]** + **"well-known-secure-suffix"**.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a coin-flipping protocol.

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like I can achieve this by simply hashing all **d[i]** values in predictable order.

That doesn't quite work; the issue is that the last one to contribute their d[i] value has seen all the previous ones, and can then quickly test candidate d[i] values, looking for one when produces the random padding they like.  This is probably not a huge vulnerability (if the protocol expects a d[i] value within a few seconds, an implementation might be able to test a few million to billions of candidate values (depending on attacker resources) before having to select one); however it is something.

The fix for that is for to have everyone submit commitments to their shares before revealing them.  For example, party i first publishes $\text{hash}( d[i] || r_i )$ to everyone, and not until everyone has published their commitments, everyone then publishes their $d[i]$ and $r_i$ values (and everyone can check that their revealed values matches their commitments).  Then, everyone can combine all the $d[i]$ values, and you then get a hash value that no one has control over.

The best an attacker can do is arrange to be the last person to reveal their $d[i], r_i$ values, and then, if the combined value isn't what they like, just refuse (or misopen their commitment).  This does allow the attacker a veto over the randomness; however for the attacker to use their veto, they have to give a hint that they are the malicious party.  You could try to avoid this by using a function that is hard to compute quickly (e.g. Argon2 with appropriate parameters); I'm not sure if it's worth the trouble...